# What's the meaning of the word "trust" in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Ambulance **trust** to send occupied vehicles to new emergency calls." ([The guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2018/sep/16/ambulance-trust-to-send-occupied-vehicles-to-new-emergency-calls))

What's the meaning of the word "[trust](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trust)" in this context?

The definitions in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trust) as well as in [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trust) aren't understandable to me in this context and I'm not sure which of the definitions if the correct one.

Answer (score 11):

It's a recent extension of the meaning "an organization that controls property and/or money for another person". In the UK, the organisation that controls a portion of the NHS (National Health Service), such as a group of hospitals, or an ambulance service, is referred to as an [NHS Trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHS_trust)

So "ambulance trust" would mean "organisation within the NHS that runs an ambulance service".

**Edit**: I at first referred to NHS trusts as charitable trusts, but alephzero corrected me in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but honestly I still don't understand what is the meaning "trust" in the extended context that you showed. Second it seems to be a verb because of the preposition there "trust **to**". Isn't it?

Comment: It is a noun. The example is not a proper sentence, it is more of a fragment. Here is an equivalent: John to send letter to neighbour

Comment: This kind of contraction is common in newspaper headlines.  We're supposed to read something like "[An] ambulance trust [plans] to send occupied vehicles ..."  There's very often ambiguity that you have to decode (or, if the ambiguity is amusing enough, send to be read out on a topical radio comedy show...)

Comment: @TobySpeight I'd say that the omitted verb is "is"; headlines typically omit both articles *and* all instances of the verb "to be". I'd say the proper expansion into a sentence here is "*An* ambulance trust *is* to send occupied vehicles ...".

Comment: @Conceivableassessment And to be explicit, "_Ambulance Trust_" (see half -way down [this NHS page](https://www.nhs.uk/using-the-nhs/about-the-nhs/nhs-authorities-and-trusts/)) is a two-word noun phrase -- the body that controls the ambulances.

Comment: @TripeHound - Thanks for pointing that out. I think even if they just capitalized "Trust" in the original phrase, it would be much more clear. I'm a native speaker (AmE though), and even I had to re-read a couple times.

Comment: There are charities which provide ambulance services in the UK (for example the St John's Ambulance service, and almost all the Air Ambulances are operated by charities) but "National Health Service Trusts" are legally distinct from "Charitable Trusts," even though the *purposes* of the two types of legal entity have much in common. NHS trusts are set up under the specific provisions of the National Health Services Act 2006. Charitable Trusts in general are regulated by the Charity Commission and the High Court.